# How can i make a row always editable?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using material-table in react. I need to make one row always editable. I cannot find the solution for this. Is there any solution?

Comment: Try adding content-editable= true to your td class.

Comment: @Anuj you want to edit on same place?

Comment: @RohanRao, I cannot able to add because material-table always create td dynamically

Comment: @VahidAkhtar, what a need is when I click the icon to add new row(not material-table Add button) it will create new row with editable.

Comment: @Anuj can you show your design?

Comment: @Anuj can you show your code /design where you have you written this material-table?

Comment: actions={[
                  {
                   icon: () => <FileCopyIcon />,
                   tooltip: 'Copy',
                   onClick: (event, rowData) => {
                   ** Functionality to add copy of row in editable mode **                                          
                   }
              }
]}


I used this action this as a prop in material-table